# fprintf variable or string

Tags: c, printf

I think I might be digging into this too deep but I am curious if there really is any difference between using fprintf with a variable or not? Other than the memory usage of x in this case.

```
fprintf(stderr,"%d", 1);
```

vs

```
int x = 1;

fprintf(stderr,"%d", x);
```

Comment: The memory usage is the same. The compiler translates the code beforehand to be better. You don't ever have to manually optimize.

Comment: @brunch875 not necessarily... Optimization is not required to be implemented.

Comment: Expressions are always evaluated, and both `1` and `x` are evaluated to the same.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference.  Both `x` and `1` are of type `int`, so there is no difference between the two as far as `printf` is concerned.

Comment: Yes, in both cases an `int` value is supplied as an argument and `printf()` won't know whether it was from a variable or an immediate value.